# How to calculate years for a Permanent Residency in Poland?

Tags: residency, poland

I was a student for a 3.5 years, and later I worked for one year. How many years count toward Permanent Residency according to "USTAWA z dnia 12grudnia 2013r.o cudzoziemcach"?

> Art.195.1.  Zezwolenia  na  pobyt  stały  udziela  się  cudzoziemcowi  na  czas nieoznaczony, na jego wniosek, jeżeli:
> 6)bezpośrednioprzed złożeniem wniosku oudzielenie  mu  zezwolenia  na  pobyt stały przebywał nieprzerwanie na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej przez okres nie krótszy niż:
> c)4 lata  na  podstawie  zezwolenia  na  pobyt  czasowy  ipracę udzielonego ze względu  na  cel,  októrym  mowa  wart.114ust.1a,   iposiada  źródło stabilnego  iregularnego  dochodu  wystarczającego  na  pokrycie  kosztów utrzymania  siebie  iczłonków rodziny pozostających najego  utrzymaniu.
>
> > Article 195.1.  A permanent residence permit is granted to a foreigner for an indefinite period, upon his / her request, if: 6) immediately prior to submitting the application for a permanent residence permit, he / she stayed continuously in the territory of the Republic of Poland for a period of at least: c) 4 years on the basis of a temporary residence permit  and employment granted for the purpose referred to in Article 114 paragraph 1a, and has a source of stable and regular income sufficient to cover the costs of maintaining himself and his dependent family members.

Comment: Probably 1, since being a student will probably not be considered **employment**. `c) 4 years on the basis of a temporary residence permit and employment`

Answer (score 0):

I would put accent on art.195 (6) Ustawy z dnia 12 grudnia 2013 r. o cudzoziemcach

> okres nie krótszy niż 5 lat ***na podstawie statusu uchodźcy, ochrony uzupełniającej lub zgody na pobyt ze względów humanitarnych***
>
> > a period of not less than 5 years ***on the basis of refugee status, subsidiary protection or permission to stay for humanitarian reasons***

-> so, if there was no such reason as in this paragraph, 5 years are not enough for getting Permanent Residence Card regarding to this paragraph